# Implementation React native google pay

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, google-pay

I am implementing it .

```
react-native-google-pay
```

It is installed and showing a login popup as expected but i am not able to get how can i test it. As there is no way to test it.

this is my code

```
const requestData = {
            cardPaymentMethod: {
                tokenizationSpecification: {
                    type: 'PAYMENT_GATEWAY',
                    gateway: 'stripe',
                    gatewayMerchantId: '',
                    stripe: {
                        publishableKey: '',
                        version: '2018-11-08',
                    }
                },
                allowedCardNetworks,
                allowedCardAuthMethods,
            },
            transaction: {
                totalPrice: amount_to_add,
                totalPriceStatus: 'FINAL',
                currencyCode: 'USD',
            },
            merchantName: 'Merchant',
        };
```

In this what is the value of gatewayMerchantId,type.

And Let me know if someone have dummy cards or a way to test it. As it is showing error, as well as no trasaction response of 200 or rejection.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done a Google Pay integration with Stripe, but *react-native-google-pay* looks like a thin wrapper around the Google Pay API. I'd suggest looking at [Google Pay's documentation](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/tutorial) to supplement the holes in the library's documentation.

In this case, I'd suggest changing the values in the tokenizationSpecification to match Google Pay's docs:

```
    const requestData = {
    cardPaymentMethod: {
        tokenizationSpecification: {
            type: 'PAYMENT_GATEWAY',
            parameters: {
                gateway: "stripe"
                "stripe:version": "2018-10-31"
                "stripe:publishableKey": "YOUR_PUBLIC_STRIPE_KEY"
            }
        },
        allowedCardNetworks,
        allowedCardAuthMethods,
    },
    transaction: {
        totalPrice: amount_to_add,
        totalPriceStatus: 'FINAL',
        currencyCode: 'USD',
    },
    merchantName: 'Merchant',
};
```

When I integrated to Google Pay, I used my real credit card number (I was unable to get anything fake into Google Pay) and enabled test mode. The library seems to support that test mode like this:

```
// Set the environment before the payment request
GooglePay.setEnvironment(GooglePay.ENVIRONMENT_TEST);
```